# How to make id field always start from 1 when a new import is made or just remove it?

Tags: python, django, database, django-import-export

I am facing problems with importing csv file into my db in django.
I don't want to add id field when I import the csv file.

app.admin/

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Products, Forimg
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

@admin.register(Products, Forimg)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

app.models/

```
class Products(models.Model):

Code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Product_description = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key = True)
Val_tech = models.CharField(max_length=5)
Quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
UOM = models.CharField(max_length=5)
Rate = models.FloatField(default=0)
Value = models.FloatField(default=0)


def __str__(self):
    return self.Product_description



class Forimg(models.Model):

products = models.OneToOneField(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img/', width_field= 30, height_field = 40)

def __str__(self):
    return self.products.Product_description
```

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the `id` field during import, you can configure your Resource to [exclude that field](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options):

```py
class YourResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        exclude = ('id', )
```

To make the id field always start at 1, then you would need to include the `id` field in your csv file:

```
id,name
1,name1
2,name2
```

Then ensure that these fields are imported.  Note that `exclude` is not used here:

```py
class YourResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        include = ('id','name')
```

If you re-import the same file, then you need to make sure that any existing rows are updated (or skipped).  To achieve this, add logic to identify the import as an 'update'.  To have the row skipped (instead of updated), enable `skip_unchanged`:

```py
class YourResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        include = ('id','name')
        import_id_fields = ('id',)
        skip_unchanged = True
```

I hope this helps to solve your issue.  If not, please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and be clearer about your issue.